# Creating an algorithm which checks if a graph is connected or not

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, time-complexity, big-o

So an old exam question was asked like that.
I was wondering what that means, because a graph can be directed or not. In a directed graph it should be working like that (I guess):

```
Create two Arrays: A[], A_inverse[] //both in size N (N nodes exists), both arrays initalized with NULL
Run depth-first search on Graph G
     save in A[] all Nodes which are visted
         If(A.size < |N|) return false
G' = Reverse all edges of G
Run depth-first search on Graph G'  
     save in A_inverse[] all Nodes which are visted
         If(A_inverse.size < |N|) return false
return true
```

For the time-complexity it is T(N) = 2*DFS + |E| + c. 2*DFS because im calling it twice (once for the G and once for G'). |E| because I need to reverse all Edges. c are all conditions and initializings.
Is my algorithm correct?

Comment: What [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)#Definitions_of_components,_cuts_and_connectivity) of "connected" are you using for a directed graph; should the algorithm test whether it's strongly or weakly connected?

Comment: @kaya3 by the algorithm, it seems to be a test for weakly connected. This "reverse-edge" thing shouldn't prove that it is strongly connected, since `u` reaches `v` one way and `v` reaches `u` the other way (with edges reversed), but `v` not necessarily reaches `u` with original edges.

Comment: The algorithm returns false if it isn’t strongly connected. It returns true if it is strongly connected. 
@daniel ur example should work for the algorithm. If v can be visited, it should be visited again, after being reversed, if the graph is strongly connected. It doesnt have to use the „original“ edges. If something is Strongly connected it can be visited again after being reversed. This is one of the characteristics of a strongly connected graph. My algorithm doesn’t work for weak connected graphs.

Comment: So this algorithm just does a workaround to turn a directed graph into a undirected graph?

Comment: No it checks if a directed graph is strongly connected or not.

Answer (score 1):

In a strongly connected graph G, there must be a path from any node A to any (other) node B.

To start, note that there is a path from B to A in the flipped graph G' if and only if there is a path from A to B in the original graph G.

Assume the DFS starts at some origin node O.

First we show that if G is strongly connected, the algorithm returns true.

- The first DFS will reach all the nodes, since by assumption there is a path from O to every other node.
- Again by assumption, there's a path from every node to O. It follows that in G' (where all edges are flipped), there's a path from O to every other node. The second DFS will therefore also reach all nodes, and the algorithm returns true.

Now consider a graph G that is not strongly connected, i.e., there's a pair of nodes (A, B) such that there exists no path from A to B. We have to show that the algorithm returns false. There are two cases to consider:

- *There is no path from A to O*. In this case, the flipped graph G' cannot contain a path from O to A. Therefore, the second DFS will not reach A from O and the algorithm returns false.
- *There is a path from A to O*: In this case, there cannot be a path from O to B because if there were, our assumption that there is no path from A to B would be wrong. Since there is no path from O to B, the first DFS will not reach B from O and the algorithm returns false.

We proved that the algorithm returns true if G is strongly connected and false otherwise. It is therefore correct.